# How do I save a managed_file to a user profile in a hook_submit

Tags: users, forms

I'm trying to save a file that the user has uploaded using my form.

My form:

```
$form['fifth']['field_cv'] = array(
        '#title' => t('CV'),
        '#type' => 'managed_file',
        '#size' => 19,
        '#upload_location' => 'public://',
    );
```

My validator using hook_validate:

```
$file = file_load($form_state['values']['fifth']['field_cv']);
// Change status to permanent.
if($file) {
    $file->status = FILE_STATUS_PERMANENT;
    file_save($file);
    file_usage_add($file, 'popover', 'document', $file->fid);
}
else {
    form_set_error('CV', t('Er is geen cv geüpload'));
}
```

So now in hook_submit how do I add this to the user? Do I need to create an extra database field for this? And should I save only the $fid ( file id ) in this field?

OR

Is there a better way so drupal takes care of this and also revisions of this field are saved?

building this in D7

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not sure how your collecting this CV (apart of registration process, on your own custom page, apart of the user profile page... whatever).

I would add a field to User Accounts at `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields`, or maybe install the [Profile2](http://drupal.org/project/profile2) module for D7 if you have alot of types of Users.

After you call `file_save($file)` if you use the [Devel](http://drupal.org/project/devel) module you'll see that `$file` should have a new value `fid` so you can then load a user account (or Profile2 profile) and give the CV `$file->fid` as the File field value.

Comment: yes I'm using devel and I see a new fid. so the best way is to create a new field `/admin/config/people/accounts/fields` using and store the fid in it? There is no special file handling field?